# Can I programmatically retrieve a gem's spec from the gem itself?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem. Is there a way to retrieve the gem's specification from within the gem itself?

Specifically, I have some metadata that I want to retrieve and display when running one of the gem's executables. Is there a way to retrieve that metadata from within the gem?

Comment: Perhaps this will give some pointer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262697/how-do-i-get-the-version-from-a-gemspec-file

Comment: @WandMaker: Yeah, I guess that could work. I'd like to query the gem database somehow, but I guess I can construct a path to the gemspec instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your gem is definitionally already loaded by this point, `Gem.loaded_specs['name-of-your-gem']` will give you what you want.

[Documentation for `Gem.loaded_specs`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubygems/rubygems/Gem.loaded_specs)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @philomony put me on the right track. Here are more details. The following was executed in a debugger:

```rb
specs = Gem.loaded_specs['jekyll_plugin_support']
#<Gem::Specification:0x00007fdcc3ba7000 ...

specs.class
Gem::Specification

specs.author
"Mike Slinn"

specs.metadata
{"allowed_push_host"=>"https://rubygems.org", "bug_tracker_uri"=>"https://github.com/mslinn/jekyll_plugin_support/issues", "changelog_uri"=>"https://github.com/mslinn/jekyll_plugin_support/CHANGELOG.md", "homepage_uri"=>"https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2020/10/03/jekyll-plugins.html#quote", "source_code_uri"=>"https://github.com/mslinn/jekyll_plugin_support"}
```

Here are the public methods:
`to_yaml`, `full_name`, `conflicts`, `remote=`, `dependencies`, `platform`, `name=`, `specification_version`, `date`, `summary`, `authors`, `autorequire`, `cert_chain`, `description`, `email`, `extensions`, `extra_rdoc_files`, `homepage`, `licenses`, `metadata`, `post_install_message`, `rdoc_options`, `required_ruby_version`, `required_rubygems_version`, `signing_key`, `<=>`, `test_files`, `==`, `relative_loaded_from`, `rg_full_gem_path`, `rg_loaded_from`, `location`, `load_paths`, `rg_required_ruby_version=`, `git_version`, `rg_extension_dir`, `nondevelopment_dependencies`, `to_gemfile`, `to_spec`, `deleted_gem?`, `eql?`, `removed_method_calls`, `add_bindir`, `authors=`, `email=`, `license=`, `metadata=`, `homepage=`, `licenses=`, `author=`, `platform=`, `signing_key=`, `bindir=`, `activated=`, `autorequire=`, `rubygems_version=`, `require_paths=`, `original_platform=`, `add_development_dependency`, `_deprecated_has_rdoc=`, `_deprecated_default_executable=`, `add_runtime_dependency`, `_deprecated_default_executable`, `installed_by_version`, `installed_by_version=`, `method_missing`, `required_ruby_version=`, `_deprecated_validate_permissions`, `required_rubygems_version=`, `_deprecated_validate_metadata`, `_deprecated_validate_dependencies`, `test_files=`, `activated`, `default_executable`, `default_executable=`, `_deprecated_has_rdoc`, `original_platform`, `_deprecated_has_rdoc?`, `location=`, `gems_dir`, `relative_loaded_from=`, `source=`, `to_s`, `inspect`, `groups`, `activated?`, `activate`, `name`, `version`, `traverse`, `requirements`, `has_conflicts?`, `conficts_when_loaded_with?`, `bin_file`, `executables`, `reset_nil_attributes_to_default`, `bindir`, `loaded_from`, `hash`, `date=`, `sort_obj`, `raise_if_conflicts`, `activate_dependencies`, `add_self_to_load_path`, `runtime_dependencies`, `files`, `spec_file`, `abbreviate`, `files=`, `rdoc_options=`, `extra_rdoc_files=`, `cert_chain=`, `sanitize`, `summary=`, `sanitize_string`, `description=`, `post_install_message=`, `add_dependency`, `author`, `bin_dir`, `build_args`, `build_info_file`, `build_extensions`, `build_info_dir`, `cache_dir`, `cache_file`, `satisfies_requirement?`, `_dump`, `default_value`, `dependent_gems`, `dependent_specs`, `development_dependencies`, `doc_dir`, `encode_with`, `mark_version`, `executable`, `executable=`, `executables=`, `extensions=`, `file_name`, `for_cache`, `rubygems_version`, `has_rdoc`, `has_rdoc=`, `has_rdoc?`, `has_unit_tests?`, `has_test_suite?`, `init_with`, `yaml_initialize`, `version=`, `lib_files`, `license`, `internal_init`, `missing_extensions?`, `name_tuple`, `pretty_print`, `original_name`, `require_path`, `require_path=`, `requirements=`, `ri_dir`, `spec_dir`, `spec_name`, `test_file`, `test_file=`, `to_ruby`, `raw_require_paths`, `source`, `to_ruby_for_cache`, `validate`, `keep_only_files_and_directories`, `validate_metadata`, `validate_dependencies`, `validate_permissions`, `stubbed?`, `specification_version=`, `extension_dir`, `full_gem_path`, `remote`, `base_dir`, `gem_dir`, `normalize`, `match_platform`, `matches_current_rubygems?`, `matches_current_ruby?`, `plugins`, `source_paths`, `datadir`, `lib_dirs_glob`, `base_dir=`, `extension_dir=`, `ignored=`, `full_gem_path=`, `require_paths`, `this`, `contains_requirable_file?`, `matches_for_glob`, `default_gem?`, `full_require_paths`, `gem_build_complete_path`, `loaded_from=`, `extensions_dir`, `to_fullpath`, `to_json`, `pretty_print_instance_variables`, `pretty_print_cycle`, `pretty_print_inspect`, `singleton_class`, `dup`, `itself`, `taint`, `tainted?`, `untaint`, `untrust`, `untrusted?`, `trust`, `methods`, `singleton_methods`, `protected_methods`, `private_methods`, `public_methods`, `instance_variables`, `instance_variable_get`, `instance_variable_set`, `instance_variable_defined?`, `remove_instance_variable`, `instance_of?`, `kind_of?`, `is_a?`, `display`, `public_send`, `class`, `frozen?`, `tap`, `then`, `extend`, `yield_self`, `clone`, `method`, `public_method`, `singleton_method`, `===`, `define_singleton_method`, `=~`, `!~`, `nil?`, `respond_to?`, `freeze`, `object_id`, `gem`, `send`, `to_enum`, `enum_for`, `pretty_inspect`, `__send__`, `!`, `__id__`, `instance_eval`, `instance_exec`, `!=`, `equal?`