# How do I get a gemspec to report its target *.gem filename?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there an easy way using the `gem` command to ask "what would your output file be"?

Use case: I am wrapping several commands with a Makefile. With the version already built into my `.gemspec` (actually into a `version.rb` that gemspec includes, but same thing...), I don't want to hard-code it *also* into my Makefile. Since generation of my output file is built into `gem build myspec.gemspec`, best would be if I could just run something like `gem tellmeoutputfile myspec.gemspec`.

I did see [How do I get the version from a gemspec file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262697/how-do-i-get-the-version-from-a-gemspec-file) which would work, but wanted to know if it is built into the `gem` command in any way?

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `gem help specification`

For example `gem specification rails version` returns:

```
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Version
version: 5.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks @DiodonHystrix, looks like a step in the right direction, but how do I get it to work? I tried `gem spec ./docker_registry2.gemspec --all` and got `ERROR:  No gem matching './docker_registry2.gemspec (>= 0)' found`.

Comment: `Usage: gem specification [GEMFILE] [FIELD] [options]`
`Arguments:
    GEMFILE       name of gem to show the gemspec for
    FIELD         name of gemspec field to show`
Looks like gemfile has to be the name of gem.

Comment: Actually, I think `gem spec` gives the reverse of what I want. `gem spec` says, "given a gem file, get the spec." I am saying the opposite: "given a gemspec file, tell me the version, etc. used to construct the gem file."

Comment: Yea, I guess that is right. Unfortunately, I don't think you can do that with `gem`.